# How to resolve "expected (), found Result" when returning a custom result?

Tags: rust

I am creating a custom `Result` such that the the `Ok` value is generic, but I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:38:13
   |
38 |             Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Not a subset"))
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`
```

With this code:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

pub type SubsetResult<T> = Result<T, SubsetError>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum SubsetError {
    Io(io::Error),
}

impl From<io::Error> for SubsetError {
    fn from(err: io::Error) -> SubsetError {
        SubsetError::Io(err)
    }
}

trait Subset {
    type T;
    fn is_subset(&self, &[i32]) -> SubsetResult<Self::T>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Set {
    dataset: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Subset for Set {
    type T = bool;

    // self is the superset
    fn is_subset(&self, subset: &[i32]) -> SubsetResult<Self::T> {
        let mut concatedsets = Vec::new();
        concatedsets.extend_from_slice(self.dataset.as_slice());
        concatedsets.extend_from_slice(subset);
        concatedsets.sort();
        concatedsets.dedup();
        if concatedsets.len() != self.dataset.len() {
            Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Not a subset"))
        }
        Ok(true)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let superset = Set { dataset: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    let subset = vec![1, 2, 4];
    let result = superset.is_subset(subset.as_slice()).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);

}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=88d6c49a6fb15982312a1c1b5867da29&version=stable))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your custom error type wraps the IO error type, you must set that in your `Err` result. And in order for the correct type to be returned you need an explicit return statement as well.

This is what it should look like:

```
return Err(SubsetError::Io(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Not a subset")));
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking is there any way sugar coat that syntax or is just the way it is for custom errors?

Comment: You may have already seen [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#error-handling-with-a-custom-type), but that is a good read. What I generally like to do is create my own error type and implement the `Error` trait for it. Then I can use that in a `Result` or make a custom `Result` as well.

Answer (score 9):

Note that the error message is because you aren't **returning** the `Err` from the function. You simply create it and it becomes the value of the `if` block. Because there is no `else` block, the type of the `else` block is `()`, so the value of the `if` expression is indeterminate: is it `()` or a `Result`?

You could either `return` the `Err` or provide an `else` block:

```
if concatedsets.len() != self.dataset.len() {
    Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Not a subset"))
} else {
    Ok(true)
}
```

That unlocks another error, which is that you aren't returning the type you say you are. An `Error` is **not** a `SubsetError`. Because you've implemented `From` for that error type, you can use `try!` or `?` to convert between types:

```
Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Not a subset"))?
```

You can also explicitly wrap the type, as [shown in squiguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002047/155423).

Comment: Your answers always seem much more elegant :)

Comment: @squiguy nah, my answers just include a lot of information based on reading lots of similar questions. It's my belief that there are only like 500 unique Rust questions and all the rest are just variations on a theme. I can draw a lot of inspiration from these almost-but-not-quite duplicates to fill in background information that people like to know. There's almost always room for multiple styles of answer!